# OpenVPN goes straight to systray

Tags: openvpn

I have OpenVPN set up and running fine. I have had an issue, not really a problem, but more of a confusion issue with my end users. When you open OpenVPN it sends the icon straight to the systray. Is there anyway to have that just automatically pop up the OpenVPN GUI after you double click on it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. The GUI is fundamentally quite simple and functional. The only UI (as such) is the right click menu found from the systray icon.

If it's confusing your users then you could create a shortcut which launches the GUI with the argument `--connect <connection>.ovpn`. This will auto-spawn the specified connection and display a baloon dialog when connected.

They would still need to get their heads around the menu if they wish to disconnect though.